# Restrict box and axis to extent in plot.raster

Tags: r, plot, raster

When plotting a raster the box around the plot and the axes are adjusted automatically:

```
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
plot(r)
```

Here, the extent is

```
extent(r)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -180 
xmax        : 180 
ymin        : -90 
ymax        : 90
```

Nevertheless, the y-axis runs from -180 to 180 and there is ugly white space on the top and the bottom of the plot. Is there a way to force the box and the y-axis to the extent of the raster layer? I fumbled around with arguments like asp, ylim etc. but could not find any solution. Which way to do that am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
plot(r, asp=NA)
```

to see if this is what you want. `?raster::plot`

Answer (score 1):

You are not saying what you are plotting to. For some devices, e.g. png you can set the height and width. In other cases, you need to resize the plotting window manually.

Comment: Thanks, works for png (which I was looking for). But is the solution not a little unhandy? For every new map with a different extent I have to noodle around and find the height and size that fits to the map. And when I use another device I have to start all over... Finally, what to do when I want to have multiple figures in a png or pdf? I had hoped there was a simpler solution....

Comment: I agree, and it could be circumvented. I will look into that.